# Static class - deferred field initialization

Tags: c#

In short, I would like to know if there is a way to delay the initialization of static fields in a class.

I can't create instances of a certain class until some other values are set. An example:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Foo.Init();
    // initialize static Bar fields
}
```

Below, `Bar` instances requires some values set in `Foo.Init()`.

```
public static class Bars
{
    public static Bar bar = new Bar();
}
```

This won't work since `Bar` fields are instantiated before `Foo.Init()` is executed.

The only solution I can think of is something like

```
public static class Bars
{
    public static Bar bar;
    public static void Init()
    {
        bar = new Bar();
    }

}
```

and run `Bars.Init()` after `Foo.Init()`.

Is this the only way to solve it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can **init** a static class using static constructors:

```
public static class Foo
{
    public static int Result { get; set; }

    static Foo()
    {
        Result = -1;
    }
}
```

read more [Here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx)

Comment: `The user has no control on when the static constructor is executed in the program`. Can I be sure that it won't be executed before `Foo.Init()`?

Comment: static constructors call first time you access on of the static members of a class, you don't need to call it your self.

Answer (score 0):

something like this:

```
private static Bar bar;
public static Bar Bar
{
    get
    {
        bar = bar ?? new Bar();
        return bar;
    }
}
```